# Kerr metric in SageMath causal visualization

Tags: manifolds, visualization, general-relativity, sagemath

I am studying the Kerr Metric via the SageMath manifolds module and would like to visualize the casual surfaces generated by light cones.  Like the circles in this picture:
[image: Light cones]

Can anybody provide clues about how to program this?  SageMath manifolds does provide geodesic ray tracing but I would like the orthogonal surfaces with controls for "elapsed time" (a fluid concept) and off-equatorial angle control for source and slices if 2-d projection is necessary.  3-D would be nice but probably too difficult.
Parametrizing the geodesics, taking orthogonal tangents, and connecting them seems like it would take a long execution time; particularly since I want to watch and control the progress/evolution of the causal boundary.
Suggestions for an alternate forum or Sagemath reference material would be most welcome.

Comment: Usually better results come to such specific questions at ask.sagemath.org - good luck!

Comment: I placed a link there, perhaps the wrong category though.